# Edit codes in .Net Reflector with Reflexil (Compile Window)

Tags: .net, decompiler, crackme

I'm Using .Net Reflector with Reflexil to edit or view .net Assembly codes.

I see this picture in reflexil.net:

[image: reflexil.net]

It Shows the "Compile" window.
How can I see this window and edit codes?

Comment: Try dnSpy, it has far superior decompilation and it properly supports this feature and many others (debugging) without plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Decompile a function with .NET Reflector, and in the **Instructions** tab of the Reflexil window, right click on an instruction and choose **Replace all with code...**:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaWtoCmOGpw#t=1m40s

Comment: Thanks @jason-geffner. Now I can open Compile Window. But I can't find the codes of decompiled program and all events are empty!

Answer (score 3):

This [blog](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/05/30/redirect-registry-by-modifying-net-executable/) that I wrote a a few years ago describes all the steps to modify a .net binary with Reflector and Reflexil. Not sure which steps you're missing but I recommended to read&compare.

However, Today I would recommend Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) though as it has built in de-obfuscation (de4dot) and has an option to replace a section with code which is much, much, easier than writing replacement code in IL.

/EDIT: Here's a [blog](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2017/03/14/modifying-net-application/) I wrote about using JustDecompile and Reflector to modify a .net binary.

Comment: Your blog link is dead.

Comment: @L29Ah I checked both links and they seem to be fine, maybe temporary issue or maintenance when you checked?

Comment: Nope, check out this traceroute: http://bpaste.net/show/8f65550128e1

Answer (score -1):

There is a nice tool to play with .NET assemblies (https://www.digitalbodyguard.com/graywolf.html)

GrayWolf – Is a reverse engineering tool
(focused on .NET Framework Applications)

Currently - is in a late beta stage It is similar to IL-Spy but this has a focue on edit/attack.
GrayWolf was a tool I created to carry out research. The focus is on editing applications to make change quickly.

What can it do:
DE-ObfuScatE,**Edit IL(Live)**, Add payloads, **Edit attributes(public/privet)**, Copy strong names signing on EXE/DLL

Comment: is this program free?

Comment: @Ayrese yes it is

Comment: While GrayWolf was a great tool in its day, I think that there are more modern and better tools for .NET reversing, such as dnSpy. dnSpy offers a nicer UI and a more robust engine (de4dot's) for handling heavily obfuscated binaries, while being able to do everything (as far as I am aware) GrayWolf can - including but not limited to IL editing.

Comment: This does not answer the question which was specifically about Reflexil